# Unity Particle Effect Optimization

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-engine, game-development, particle-system

I am making a snowy map in Unity and I want to add particles that simulate snow all over the map. The problem is that the map is relatively large and if I change the number of particles spawned to a bigger value, the game runs very poorly. I know I can do so that the particles are present only near the player but that is not what I want. Isn't there a way to optimize the particle when the number of instances is very big? Maybe something related to rendering?

Thanks!

Comment: Do it in an area over the player when in that map area

Comment: @BugFinder I'll stick to this I guess. Thank you!!

Comment: Do what BugFinder suggested, but also change the simulation space to global